# ADB connection with Android emulator breaks

Tags: android, sdk, adb, emulation, device

I am trying to connect with android emulator using ADB. I can connect with device but every time after a while ( about 10 seconds) connection breaks. 
I used to work with adb some time ago and everything was correct.

I tried to restart adb, reinstall adb, I checked settings of emulator and still there is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Android Studio version is the latest, I had this problem on Mac when Nougat was just released. You can try the dev channel if the stable channel doesn't work

Switching Android Studio build channle: http://tools.android.com/preview-channel

Comment: I've just started work with android, maybe there is another solution to manage SQLite database? I have to make simple application. Something like database manager form Intellij IDEA would be great. I just want to know what rows are in table ... etc.

Comment: Use Stetho, it an excellent tool developed by Facebook (http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)